# Unexpected output for http_build_query (& => ¶ms)

Tags: php

Trying to send the following array in url:

```
$params = [
    'a' => 'x',
    'b' => 'y'
];
$url = http_build_query(['params' => $params]);
echo urldecode($url);
```

I was expecting this output:

```
params[a]=x&params[b]=y
```

But I'm getting this instead:

```
params[a]=x¶ms[b]=y
```

I have also tried:

```
http_build_query(['params' => $params], '', '&');
http_build_query(['params' => $params], null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
http_build_query(['params' => $params], null, ini_get('arg_separator.output'), PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

and:

```
$params = [
    'params[a]' => 'x',
    'params[b]' => 'y'
];
```

But I keep getting the same output. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is it my server? *(Apache/2.4.33 - Unix - PHP/7.2.6)*

---

Following @Sammitch suggestion:

```
var_dump($url, bin2hex($url), urldecode($url), bin2hex(urldecode($url)));
```

outputs:

```
string(31) "params%5Ba%5D=x&params%5Bb%5D=y"
string(62) "706172616d73253542612535443d7826706172616d73253542622535443d79"
string(23) "params[a]=x&params[b]=y"
string(46) "706172616d735b615d3d7826706172616d735b625d3d79"
```

Comment: Replace that `echo` with `var_dump($url, bin2hex($url), urldecode($url), bin2hex(urldecode($url)));` and add the output to the question.

Comment: Also, are you piping this output through anything else like an XML document or something? It looks like something might be incorrectly converting `&para` as the `&para;` XML entity which will then show up as that problematic symbol.

Comment: Works fine on [rextester](http://rextester.com/VWY20270). Are you post-processing your output before you see it?

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch. I added requested output. It looks correct there. And yes you are right it seems `&para;` getting converted even if I tried that in a simple php file out of my project. Is there a way to avoid that conversion? I can't choose different url param.

Comment: It's probably being interpreted by the browser. Use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode it so you see everything literally.

Comment: Thanks @Nick it seems to work fine in rextester but I tested it with different PHP versions here and got same results as mine: http://http_build_query.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: As @Barmar points out, if you use `htmlspecialchars()` it works fine on `onlinephpfunctions.com` as well. So it would seem a browser error since `&para` without a trailing `;` should not be interpreted as `&para;`

Comment: Yes `htmlspecialchars()` shows it correctly. It was the browser. Thank you @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you view here is correct

```
params[a]=x¶ms[b]=y
```

as

```
&para
```

represents a special character

```
¶
```

hence

```
&params
```

turn into

```
¶ms
```

if you still want to see it the way you want to make a small change to the echo only as follows

```
echo str_replace('&','<span>&</span>',urldecode($url)).'</code>';
```

Comment: I'd go with `htmlspecialchars()` but that also fixes it. Thank you.